# Winform User Control size switch back to initial size after localized

Tags: c#, winforms

this is my first thread on this great website for programming :)

I have a problem with my UC. I'm currently developing an extended version of DataGridView, which added some functionality like paging support.

Here is the picture of the UC inside a form, after I make it bigger than the initial size:

[image: Resizes the UC]

And finally, I change the form's language to Indonesian. And then the designer suddenly repaint my UC. The size of the container of my UC is OK, means the designer remembers that I resized my UC before. But unfortunately the controls inside the UC's container gets switched back to their initial size, leave some blank spaces inside. This behaviour only happen in design time. The UC is fine in runtime mode, its size works well.

[image: Controls inside the UC switched back to their initial size]

How could this happen guys? Although it's fine in runtime, but it's ugly in design time.
Sorry for my English, greeting from Indonesian :)
Thanks.

===SOLUTION===

After play a bit, finally I've found the solution. Before I place the controls inside to the container, I must first add a Panel to the container, set it to transparent, and set its Dock property to Fill. Then followed by DataGridView and BindingNavigator to the rest. Build and it works like a charm!

It seems that the Panel resolves the problem :)

Cheers

Comment: How do you implement the layout for that user control? By setting anchor, setting docker or absolute position?

Comment: @xtu i have already play with all that properties :) . Everything works fine with that anchor and docker settings. The problem is only when the localization changed. The designer repaint my UC and unfortunately I dont know how to keep the size. The Panel I mentioned above resolves my headache :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help to change the order of the factors.  First change the `Form` language to Indonesian.  Then save your project and close it.  Open it again and check if it still on Indonesian then place the `DataGridView` control on the form and re-size it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't. The designer must be in the Default language before we can drop some controls :)